# Mergesort in Racket in R5RS

Tags: algorithm, syntax-error, racket, mergesort, r5rs

## I'm trying to write mergesort in Racket (in R5RS).

#### I'm not sure how I'm getting so many syntax errors.

---

So, I've learned from the help of those who commented that I was actually writing in R and not R5RS. I'm new to learning either language so I would appreciate any help with how to write a mergesort method in R5RS. I removed most of the causes of the syntax errors such as

> Illegal use of '['

but then it didn't do anything.

---

This is the code I had before fixing the program

```
(define (merge as bs)
        (match* (as bs)
        [((list) bs) bs]
        [(as (list)) as]
        [((list a as ...) (list b bs ...))
(if (< a b)
        (cons a (merge as (cons b bs)))
        (cons b (merge (cons a as) bs)))]))
(define (mergesort vs)
        (match vs
        [(list) vs]
        [(list a) vs]
[_ (define-values (lvs rvs)
        (split-at vs (quotient (length vs) 2)))
        (merge (mergesort lvs) (mergesort rvs))]))
```

This is after I fixed it but it still didn't work

```
(define (merge as bs)
        (match* (as bs)
        ((list) bs) bs
        (as (list)) as
        ((list a as ...) (list b bs ...))
(if (< a b)
        (cons a (merge as (cons b bs)))
        (cons b (merge (cons a as) bs)))))

(define (mergesort vs)
        (match vs
        (list) vs
        (list a) vs
(define-values (lvs rvs)
        (split-at vs (quotient (length vs) 2)))
        (merge (mergesort lvs) (mergesort rvs))))
```

EDIT: I appreciate the help with understanding the mistake I made here. I have formatted the code better so it is indented.

Comment: Either use `#lang racket` or rewrite all your code to conform to R5RS, removing the Racket-specific syntax.

Comment: And for heavens’ sake, please indent your code, it’s impossible to read or understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Racket's R5RS language you need to write programs which are in that language: it won't work to write programs in some other language.  In this case, `match` at least is not R5RS, and I strongly suspect `split-at` and `define-values` are not either.

What you're doing is a bit like pointing a FORTRAN 77 compiler at a Fortran 2018 program and expecting it to cope.

(Also: indent your code!)

Comment: I indented my code, thank you for the tip. This really helped me figure out what I was doing wrong.